# Is there a nontrivial maximally recursive function?

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory

Say that a (recursive) function $f:\Bbb N\rightarrow\Bbb N$ is *maximally* recursive if, for all $n\in\Bbb N$, the value $f(n+1)$ can be calculated only by first knowing $f(n)$. A rather trivial example of a non-maximally recursive function is $f(n)=n\;(n\in \Bbb N)$: to "calculate" $f(n)$ for a given $n$, just repeat the given number; there is no need to know what $f(n-1)$ is first (although obviously that could be "calculated" too if one wished). A somewhat less trivial example of a non-maximally recursive function is $f(n)=2^n\;(n\in \Bbb N)$. We can calculate $f(16)$, for example, via $f(1)=2, f(2)=f(1)^2=4, f(4)=f(2)^2=16$,   $f(8)=f(4)^2=256$, and $f(16)= f(8)^2=65,536$; we don't need to calculate $f(3),f(5)$, $f(6),f(7),$ or $f(9),...,f(15)$. There is certainly a trivial maximally recursive function: just take $f(n)=c$, where $c$ is a constant. "Calculating" $f(n+1)$ entails calculating $f(n)$, for all $n\in\Bbb N$, trivially. But is there a nontrivial (i.e. nonconstant) provably maximally recursive function?

My best stab at answering this is $$f(0)=2,\qquad f(n+1)=\min\{p\in\Bbb P:p>f(n)^2\}\;\,(n\in\Bbb N),$$where $\Bbb P$ is the set of prime numbers. Arguably, we have to know $f(n)$ exactly before calculating $f(n+1)$, because a number as low as $f(n)^2+4$ may or may not be prime, while $f(n)^2-2$, which is disqualified, may or may not be prime, too. However, I admit that this argument is not a proof.

**Edit:** In the above, I think that you need to interpret "$f(n+1)$ can be calculated only by knowing $f(n)$" as "$f(n+1)$ cannot be calculated in any simpler way than via the calculation of $f(n)$". That is, if $B$ is an algorithm that computes $f$, say on a universal Turing machine, and $g(n)$ is an upper bound for the number of steps required by $B$ to calculate $f(n)$, then there is an algorithm $A$, which computes $f(n+1)$ only after computing $f(n)$, such that the number of steps needed by $A$ to compute $f(n)$ is also bounded by $g(n)$, for all sufficiently large $n$. Here, the qualification "sufficiently large" is introduced to ban "cheating" algorithms which are furnished (say) with a look-up crib for some finite number of values of $f$.

(This question was earlier posted by a user on MathStackExchange, and then deleted. It received only my attempt at an answer, as above. I suggested that the OP post it here to get a better answer, but he or she appears not to have done this.)

Comment: The definition of "maximally recursive" looks like it would be difficult to make precise.  What if you computed $f(n)-1$, and used that to calculate $f(n+1)$, but never bothered to add 1?

Comment: @S.Carnahan: Good comment. I have tried to make the idea precise in the edit.

Comment: Can you say in a precise way what it means for algorithm $A$ to compute $f(n+1)$ "only after computing $f(n)$"? Does $f(n)$ have to appear on the tape explicitly? Does it have to appear in a particular place on the tape? What if it appears in a disguised manner (such as by flipping bits, or interwoven with something else); would that count? Although I find the idea sensible in an informal intuitive way, I'm not clear on the precise formalization. But it seems to me that you need a precise formalization here to have an actual mathematical question.

Comment: In addition to the whole concept making no sense, the word "provably" in the title is abused in the typical computer sciency sort of way. It doesn't mean anything and it should be deleted. In fact, I am deleting it.

Comment: The notion of maximally recursive is flawed. In your edit you just replaced it with another flawed (or at least unclear) notion which is "simpler way to calculate".

Comment: I accept the comments about the lack of specification in the question. I will need to come back with a clearer question rather than sticking more patches on it in an attempt to clarify it. I'll leave it up for a while in case there are further helpful comments or answers.

Comment: It seems to me that you might fruitfully use François's idea, that the formal notion you are trying to get at may be captured by comparing the difficulty of computing $f(n+1)$ as a function of $(n,f(n))$ and conversely.

Answer (score 5):

[Course of values functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Course-of-values_recursion) all have this kind of property, though you should consider an encoding of sequences that is appropriate for your model of computation.

For example, the following should work if your model of computation has facility with binary arithmetic. Suppose $f$ is a $\{0,1\}$-valued computable function. Function $$\bar{f}(n) = \sum_{m=0}^n f(m)2^{n-m}$$ satisfies the recursive equation 
$$\bar{f}(n+1) = f(n) + 2\bar{f}(n).$$
Since your model of computation has facility with binary arithmetic the right shift (multiplication by 2) and left shift (division by 2) of an $n$-bit number should take about the same time. This equation makes it even easier to recover $\bar{f}(n)$ from $\bar{f}(n+1)$ than it is to compute $\bar{f}(n+1)$ from $\bar{f}(n)$ since the latter doesn't even involve the extra step of computing $f(n)$. So the time to compute $\bar{f}(n+1)$ can't be significantly smaller than the time it takes to compute $\bar{f}(n)$.